# What is the difference between 가장 and 제일?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage, difference

They both mean "most" (I think?) so what's the difference between them? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they both mean "most" and are almost interchangeable. But sometimes [제일第一](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/bb7220fb013c4b059d285cac1d9693e2) can be used as a noun, meaning "the best", while [가장](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/d400c8690af14cc7b2676744a3c527af)(pure korean) is never used as a noun. There is a different word [가장家長](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/f6ffe7f264f847599b72c315ff514cd3) which is a noun, but it has completely different meaning.

Comment: One note, "가장" can also be a noun, just a different meaning (a person who is leading the family; husband). However, I know that that's not what Kasturi Mone asked for.

Comment: @David Lee Well, I already mentioned that in my answer, probably you didn't read the last line? Also, there are yet another word 가장假裝, which means "to pretend (to be someone else/to have certain authority)" this is almost always used as a verb 가장하다.

Comment: My bad, should have read your answer more carefully.